# How to check if property does not exist when find in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this code:

```
 showInforme(){
    this.buscadorService.getInforme()
      .subscribe((data: InformesCounter) => {
          const { data: myData, included: myIncluded } = data;
          myData.forEach((item: any) => {
            const myFid = myIncluded.find((element: any) => element.attributes.drupal_internal__fid === item.relationships.informe.data.meta.drupal_internal__target_id)
              item.relationships.informe.data.meta.uri = myFid.attributes.uri;
            });
          // console.log(myData);
          this.infoFile = myData.map((data: { relationships: any;}) => data.relationships);
          // console.log(this.infoFile);
      })
  }
```

But when drupal_internal__target_id is not found or does not exist i receive this error in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'meta')
```

I need a way to skip each item who don't have this property. I don't know yet how can i do this. Thanks

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="button">
                                                   <span *ngIf="infoFile">
                                                      <a href="http://localhost{{infoFile[i]?.informe?.data?.meta.uri.url}}" target="_blank" hreflang="es">Informe</a>
                                                   </span>
                                                </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ? to check whether item exist aren't . so that you can avoid accessing undefined  object.

```
const myFid = myIncluded.find((element: any) => element.attributes.drupal_internal__fid === item.relationships.informe?.data?.meta?.drupal_internal__target_id)
    item.relationships.informe.data.meta.uri = myFid.attributes.uri;
});
```

For hiding in UI

```
 <button type = "button" class = "button" *ngIf="infoFile[i]?.informe?.data?.meta?.uri?.url ? true: false">
     <span *ngIf = "infoFile">
     <a href = "http://localhost{{infoFile[i]?.informe?.data?.meta.uri.url}}" target = "_blank" hreflang = "es" > Informe <  / a >
     </span >
  </button >
```

Comment: Great! I solved it by adding another span above and checking if it is null but your solution works also!!!

Answer (score 1):

You cna do this:

```
 const myFid = myIncluded.find((element: any) => element.attributes.drupal_internal__fid === item.relationships.informe.data?.meta.drupal_internal__target_id)
```

Add ? because item.relationships.informe.data is null.
In this way the error is escaped.

Comment: That works but if the item not exists i don't want to display it in view... I updated the code with the html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to prevent the error.

Add the optional chaining operator `?.` when you expect a `null` or `undefined` value and need to access a property. Example: `item.relationships.informe.data?.meta?.drupal_internal__target_id` and it will return `null`. Pay attention to the `?.` Operator after the `data` and `meta` property.

More information about Optional Chaining can be found in the [What's new in TypeScript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) article.